# How to deal with device settings in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application supporting Android, iOS, and UWP. I need the application at the starting point to check if location feature is enabled, and if not, suggest the user to do so, and let him open device Settings. But if the user agrees to open the Settings, I would need the application to wait for the results, and then continue based on the newly changed settings. But how can I make the execution wait for the user to finish working with the settings?

Here is the code I have for now:

```
           Task<bool> task = Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert("Location service is disabled on this device", 
                "MyCompany Mobile uses your location to provide you with the correct product mix and other information for your market. Please go into Settings and turn on Location for the device.", 
                "Settings", 
                "Maybe Later");

            if (task == null)
            {
                return bu;
            }

            bool result = await task;
            if (result)
            {
                IDeviceService deviceService = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceService>();
                if (deviceService != null)
                {
                    bool openedSuccessfully = await deviceService.OpenDeviceSettingsAsync();
                }
            }
```

Comment: if they can't use your app without Location, then just do nothing.  When they return to the app in OnResume just repeat the check, or give them a button on the UI to indicate that they've enabled location services, and check again when they tap it

Comment: @Jason Thank you for your help. Actually, the app can work using a default location, but I need to let the users know what is going on, and give them a choice. Is it possible maybe instead of opening Settings just to show them a Yes/No alert to enable the location feature?

Comment: Sure, you can check the location permissions and show them any sort of UI you want

Comment: @Jason  Hmm, I tried to find how it can be done, but it seems like it is impossible: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/317753/#Comment_317753

Is it true?

Comment: oh, you mean actually using your own UI to make the change.  No, that would be a huge security issue.  But you can show them a message telling them what they need to do.

Comment: @Jason Thank you Jason. If you make this your answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: You should use the Xamarin.Essentials nuget package. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=uwp

Comment: @Frédéric THEVENON I do use it.

Comment: According to the documentation : "The Geolocation API will also prompt the user for permissions when necessary.". It works fine for Android, but i didnt try on UWP.

Comment: "Frédéric THEVENON That is true, but my issue is not with permission for an app, but with the feature being disabled on the device.